# How to put an alert box in ajax if all inputs are empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

i would like to know how to put an alert box if all the variables are empty in ajax? i mean when i click the button and all the fields are empty it will pop-op and say please fill the field first...how can i do that?

current script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#updates').click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        var data = {};
        data.region_text = $('#t_region').val();
        data.town_text = $('#t_town').val();
        data.uniq_id_text = $('#t_uniq_id').val();
        data.position_text = $('#t_position').val();
        data.salary_grade_text = $('#t_salary_grade').val();
        data.salary_text = $('#t_salary').val();

        for(var $x=1;$x<=15;$x++) {
            data['id'+$x+'_text'] = $('#id'+$x).val();
            data['aic'+$x+'_text'] = $('#aic'+$x).val();
            data['name'+$x+'_text'] = $('#name'+$x).val();
            data['optA'+$x+'_text'] = $('#optA'+$x).val();
            data['optB'+$x+'_text'] = $('#optB'+$x).val();
            data['optC'+$x+'_text'] = $('#optC'+$x).val();
            data['optD'+$x+'_text'] = $('#optD'+$x).val();
            data['other_qual'+$x+'_text'] = $('#other_qual'+$x).val();
            data['interview'+$x+'_text'] = $('#interview'+$x).val();
            data['total'+$x+'_text'] = $('#total'+$x).val();
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
            if (Number(response) == 1)
        {
    alert("cant saved again!");
        }
        else
        {
    alert("successfully saved!");
        }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

insert.php code:

```
<?php
    include('../connection.php');
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');  

    $region        = @$_POST['region_text'];
    $town          = @$_POST['town_text'];
    $uniq_id       = @$_POST['uniq_id_text'];
    $position      = @$_POST['position_text'];
    $salary_grade  = @$_POST['salary_grade_text'];
    $salary        = @$_POST['salary_text'];

$dupesql = "SELECT * FROM afnup_worksheet WHERE funiq_id = '$uniq_id'";
$duperow = mysql_query($dupesql);
if(mysql_num_rows($duperow) > 0){
    echo "1";
    exit;
}else{
    echo "2";
    for($n=1;$n<=15;$n++)   {


    $id           = @$_POST['id'.$n.'_text'];
    $aic          = @$_POST['aic'.$n.'_text'];
    $name         = @$_POST['name'.$n.'_text'];
    $optA         = @$_POST['optA'.$n.'_text'];
    $optB         = @$_POST['optB'.$n.'_text'];
    $optC         = @$_POST['optC'.$n.'_text'];
    $optD         = @$_POST['optD'.$n.'_text'];
    $other_qual   = @$_POST['other_qual'.$n.'_text'];
    $interview    = @$_POST['interview'.$n.'_text'];
    $total        = @$_POST['total'.$n.'_text'];



if(!empty($name)){
$query = "INSERT INTO afnup_worksheet (faic,fregion,ftown,funiq_id,fposition,fsalary_grade,fsalary,fnl_name,edu_attain,experience,seminars,eligibility,other_qual,interview,ftotal,dateinputed) 
VALUES 
('$aic','$region','$town','$uniq_id','$position','$salary_grade','$salary','$name','$optA','$optB','$optC','$optD','$other_qual','$interview','$total',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
$resource = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You have to validate html form until make them process with Ajax

Comment: Couldn't you use `required` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab all inputs, filter for empty, and pop the alert based on that:

```
var emptyFields = $(':input').filter(function () { return this.value === '' });

if (emptyFields.length) {
    alert('Fill out all forms fields');
}
else {
    // other code here.
}
```

If you take this approach, I would write it around the entire click method. This would result in you validating the form, before making any attempt to process the data. It may save time, in the instance where the form fails validation; especially if it is a common occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert in your loop a variable like this:

```
var bool = true;
for(var $x=1;$x<=15;$x++) {
    // ... your code ...
    bool = bool && ($('#id'+$x).val() != "");
    // do like the above for all the fields
}
// at this point if at least one of your fields is empty, bool will be false

if (bool) {
    // your ajax call here, if all fields are not empty bool == true
} else {
    alert("Please fill all the fields first");
}
```

I hope I got what you needed, the question is a little unclear